# Get column name and value from a string using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to read data and column name from a string using JQuery.

My JSon String seems like below.

```
[{"ID":{"TestingID":11,"TestingTypeID":2,"Name":"SAT Test (K- 1st)","Note":"test","TestingTypes":null,"TestingGradeLevles":null,"TestingPriceLevels":null},"Early Bird":90.00,"Value Pricing":90.00,"Standard Pricing":90.00}]
```

How can I read values and Column name from above string using JQuery? Here column name and values are dynamic.

Comment: Maybe you should try something for yourself! First, convert your JSON string into an actual javascript object (using JSON.Parse), then you need to be more specific about your "dynamic columns names", how would you expect to select a property when you don't even know what it's called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `json string` is already json (not string).
Created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMbCd/2/) to show you how to get the properties and its value; Try:

```
var json = [
   {
      "ID":{
         "TestingID":11,
         "TestingTypeID":2,
         "Name":"SAT Test (K- 1st)",
         "Note":"test",
         "TestingTypes":null,
         "TestingGradeLevles":null,
         "TestingPriceLevels":null
      },
      "Early Bird":90.00,
      "Value Pricing":90.00,
      "Standard Pricing":90.00
   }
];

var index;
for (index=0; index<json.length; index++) {
    var obj = json[index];
    $.each(obj, function(value, key) {
        console.log(value, " =", key);
    });
}
```

Comment: not showing first object values, it is showing like ID=[object Object] ?

Comment: that again is a json object which can also be accessed as a json object...

Comment: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMbCd/1/);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is actually a string, you can use [jQuery's `$.parseJSON()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert it into an object:

```
var string = '[{"ID":{"TestingID":11,"TestingTypeID":2,
                "Name":"SAT Test (K- 1st)","Note":"test","TestingTypes":null,
                "TestingGradeLevles":null,"TestingPriceLevels":null},
                "Early Bird":90.00,"Value Pricing":90.00,"Standard Pricing":90.00
              }]';

var parsed = $.parseJSON(string);
```

[image: Screenshot]

You can then read the properties using:

```
parsed[0].prop;
```

For example:

```
alert(parsed[0].ID.Note); // "test"
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/WAdFC/).

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your json string to json object using

```
var result=JSON.parse(jsonstring);
```

now u can easily fetch the value by

```
result["Early Bird"];
```

This will do the stuff...

in order to convert your json string to object you need to include json2.js in your web page.